# red colour detection

Tags: opencv, ros-hydro, usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to detect red colour in ros hydro on ubuntu 12.04.
i am using opencv .
how do i do it i am usinga usb_cam driver

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133816/red-colour-detection/) by [deepak.shankar94](https://answers.ros.org/users/11771/deepak.shankar94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The cmvision package looks like it's set up to do this fairly well.

It's documented on the ROS Wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/cmvision

And they also have a nice [tutorial](http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Detect_Blobs_using_ROS_Package_cmvision)

Note that, because ROS nodes communicate over standardized messages, you should be able to use any of the vision processing nodes with any of the camera drivers.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1